# Java Strategy for mapping byte array contents to value classes

Tags: java, mapping

My goal is to improve a Java application to write data from a serial port to a MySQL database.

The data is read as a byteArray with a fixed length, which contains different values and value types (String, Int, Float, etc).

Currently, my approach is this:

```
byte[] myReadData =  {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x05);
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(0,4).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getFloat();
int i = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(5,6).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
short s = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(6,6).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getShort;
Example myExample = new Example();
myExample.setmyFloatValue(f);
myExample.setmyIntvalue(i);
myExample.setmyShortValue(s);
```

Data-Frames can be much larger and contain a lot of different data types, but all of them are d.

To read and write to the database, I use hibernate and values classes. For above example looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="example)
public class Example{
   @Id
   @Getter @Setter
   Integer id;
   @Column(name="TIMESTAMP")
   @Getter @Setter
   Timestamp Timestamp
   Column(name="FLOATVAL")
   @Getter @Setter
   float myFloatValue;
   Column(name="INTVAL")
   @Getter @Setter
   int myIntValue;
   Column(name="SHORTVAL")
   @Getter @Setter
   short myShortValue;
}
```

data frames
When using bigger data frames, the first method is not optimal and requires a lot of calculating the `copyofRange(x,y)`. It would be better to have an object with the values and automatically get the value from the data frame by their size.

In Language C, it would be doable much better with a struct, and then memcopy.
Is there a similar way in Java or how could this be done in a faster and better way?

Comment: You question needs a bit of clarification but essentially your `Example` class models a `DataFrame` which can a number of values of different types. That data comes from a `byte` array which can have an arbitrary length? After that I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: I'm looking for an easier way to not have to code all the array positions and rather have them automatically calculated and assigned to the value class. I know that i could do this easily with memcopy and struct in C, but I don't know a similar method in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single ByteBuffer, and you don’t need to copy the byte array or specify explicit indices:

```
byte[] myReadData = /* ... */;

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(myReadData);

float f = buffer.getFloat();
int i = buffer.getInt();
short s = buffer.getShort();
```

Each get-method of ByteBuffer which doesn’t take any arguments will automatically advance the buffer’s position.

No need to set the byte order.  From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#access-to-binary-data-heading):

> The initial order of a byte buffer is always `BIG_ENDIAN`.